# What does eof() returns?

Tags: c++, eof, c-str

Here is the code:

```
string fname = "/home/jack/example.csv";
ifstream csvin(fname.c_str());
if (csvin.eof()) {
    do_something;
}
```

My question is: In what case `eof()` returns true. I have the following options:

1. File does not exist.
2. File is empty.
3. File either does not exist or it is empty.

Unfortunately [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/) does not help since I do not know `eofbit error state flag` means. I also do not understand what `End-of-File is reached in the sequence associated with the stream` mean. I assume that c_str() returns some iterator and if it is already used by something it might already reach its end. However, I am interested in simple case when result of `c_str()` is fresh, what will it return if file does not exist and what will it return if file is empty?

**EDITED**

I just would like to know what the above given code returns in two cases:

1. File does not exist.
2. File is empty.

Comment: Usually, it's written like this: while(!csvin.eof()) {do_something();}

Comment: @Gearoid No. Unless by "usually," you mean "usually, in broken code,"

Comment: Your *documentation* has led has led you in a loop, as **that website is prone to do**.  Consider this site as your first source.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof

Comment: In case the file does not exist, `csvin` is not valid, and you shouldn't have attempted to call `eof()` on it in the first place...

Comment: @DevSolar: `csvin` will be a fully constructed object, so calling any method on it (including `eof`) is well defined (albeit useless in the case of `eof`). The failing constructor will set the failbit which will prevent further operations that require a valid stream from succeeding.

Comment: `c_str() is fresh` seems to be a typo, did you mean `csvin is fresh` instead?

Answer (score 4):

**eof()** returns true when the position you are at in the stream you are reading from is has reached the end of the file. It actually returns the value of the **eof flag** that gets set when the end of the file has been read (attempted to read past). Check out [C++: .eof on an empty file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134242/c-eof-on-an-empty-file) for a discussion on eof and empty files!

Comment: It would be nice with some reasons for downvoting.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer is not correct. The eof bit is set when you tried to read *past* the end of the file. If you just read the last byte, eof is **not** set yet. That's why so many `while ( ! eof() )` constructs fail so miserably: They assume that, because the last operation was successful, the next one will succeed as well...

Answer (score 2):

`eof` returns `true` if the eofbit flag is set (indicating that the end of the file is reached in the case of an `ifstream`).

The eofbit flag can be set by all input operations on the stream (eg. a `read`) when the input operation tries to read past the end of the stream (iow : the end of the stream is reached). As pointed out in a comment, even though conceptually the end of the stream is reached as soon as the last character is read (or without reading anything on an empty stream), the stream doesn't know that until it tries to read another character. Refer to the documentation for each input operation for further details.

Note that constructing the stream is not an input operation, so in the code sample that you showed, the eofbit would not be set by the time it reaches the `if` statement.
If constructing the stream fails for some reason (eg. a file that doesn't exist), then the failbit would be set, which can be checked with `fail`.

*EDIT*: Seeing your edit, I'll state the above hopefully a bit more clearly :

In the code you posted, the `if` condition would never evaluate to true, because the `ifstream` constructor does not set the eofbit.

In the case the file doesn't exist, the failbit would be set, which you can check like so :

```
if (csvin.fail()) {
    // oops : failed to open the file for reading (file doesn't exist, or has the wrong permissions, or ...)
}
```

In the case the file is empty, the constructor will not complain, but the very first input operation on the stream will set the eofbit. After that very first input operation, you can then check with `eof` if the end of the file was reached or not.

Comment: Your second paragraph is ambiguous.  What do you mean by "the end of stream is reached"?  If I open an empty file, I've "reached" the end of the stream before I attempt any input.  I think you should clarify this somewhat.  (The key is, of course, that the stream has attempted to look at a character, and there wasn't one.  Although that also begs the question: when does the stream attempt to look at a character.  Some input requires look-ahead, other doesn't.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: fair point, and added some clarification accordingly. When talking about "reaching the end of the stream", I was talking from the pov of the stream code - not conceptually. There is indeed an ambiguity between the two.

Answer (score 1):

`eof()` returns `true` if the *last operation* on the stream attempted to read past the last byte of the file. Pay attention to the fact that it tells you something about the success of the last operation and not about the success of the next one. Many code samples makes the wrong assumption that it tells you something about the next operation and thus have code that will not behave as expected.

Comment: I disagree with your second sentence.  But it depends on what `eof()` returns (and whether the operation succeeded or not).  If `eof()` returns true, it does tell you that the next operation will fail.  If it returns false, it tells you that the preceding operation didn't fail because of end of file.  (It might have failed for other reasons.)

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a small degree of implementation dependency as
to when the `eofbit` is set.  (The function `eof()` returns true
if and only if the `eofbit` is set.)  It is required to be set
if, in the course of reading something (formatted or
unformatted), a call to `streambuf::sgetc()` (or one of the
other character getters) returns `std::char_traits::eof()`.
It's not always clear when the implementation may look one
character ahead—if it gets an end of file doing so, it
sets `eofbit`; if it doesn't do the look-ahead, it doesn't.

I'm also unsure as to whether an implementation can set `eofbit`
in cases where it knows that the next read must return `eof`,
without actually having done the read; I'm fairly sure that
existing implementations don't, however.  (Do you really want
the `eofbit` set when you seek to the end of file?)  So in your
example, you will almost surely never see `eof()` returning
true.

All of this explains *why* you almost never do `input.eof()` (or
`input.good()`, which includes the `eofbit` in its value as
well).  After trying to open the file, the usual condition is
`if ( input.is_open() )`, although `input.fail()` can be used as
well.  When reading an already opened file, we test
`input.fail()` *after* the attempted input, usually by using the
stream object in a boolean context (i.e. `if ( input )`, or `if
( !input )`).  *After* having detected failure, we may use
`eof()` to determine whether the reason for failure was the end
of file, or some other error (like `"abc"` when trying to input
an `int`).  Even then, it's not 100% infallible, and `eof()` may
return true even if there was an error in the format.
(Consider:

```
std::istringstream s( "1.3E+" );
double d;
s >> d;
```

In this case, `s.eof()` will almost certainly return true,
dispite the fact that the input fails because of an error in the
format, and *not* because of end of file.)